# CSS - wrap a div inside a responsive element?

Tags: css, responsive-design

This is a more abstract than a specific problem I am facing here...I have a webpage that I have designed and I have made some of it responsive, but what I want to know is if there is a way to wrap a div element(s) inside an element that will automatically keep the aspect ratio of the contents when the viewport changes.

For instance, let's say I have a div that's 100px wide. Then I wrap some element around it and when the viewport changes to half the size it previously was then my original div will adjust itself to be 50px now.

Does this exist? If not why not?

Comment: _“Does this exist?”_ - depends on the specifics of what you mean, which so far are rather - unspecific … If you set those 100px as a fixed width, then no, there is nothing like that. If those 100px however _resulted_ out of the viewport width to begin with (f.e. specified in percentage, vw unit), then you get this result automatically and “for free”.

Answer (score 0):

What i think you mean is a media query that adjust a specific css element whenever the viewport size halves,

For example i want the font size to change as soon as my viewport width goes below or above 600 pixels

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.mobilefont {
    font-size: 7vw;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.mobilefont {
    font-size: 13vw;}
}
```

You can use the @media screen attribute to change certain values bases on the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You must use percentage for that kind of responsiveness,

e.g.

```
div {
 width: 100%;
}
```